# User count only for role frontend vendor

Tags: users, front-end, count

i use the following code for count the authors

```
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'download' );
    echo 'Published eBook (' . $count_posts->publish .  ')';
    echo ' ';
    global $wpdb; 
    $user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users;" );
    echo '  Published Authors (' . $user_count . ')';
```

i need a count from authors who have the role frontend vendor or
who have published a downlaod post.

any idea?
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

to get the number of authors who are assigned a particular role the `get_users()` function should do it:

```
$args = array(
'role' => 'frontend_vendor',//substitute your role here as needed
'fields' => 'ID',
);

$users = get_users( $args );
$user_count = count( $users );
```